# Concatenate data from two fields ignoring NULL values in one of them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Dataset is following:

```
FirstName          LastName       city      street        housenum
john            silver            london   ukitgam         780/19
gret            garbo             berlin   akstrass         102
le              chen             berlin    oppenhaim        NULL
daniel          defo             rome      corso vinchi     25
maggi           forth           london     bolken str      NULL
voich           lutz            paris      pinchi platz     NULL
anna           poperplatz        milan     via domani       15/4
```

write following query:

```
SELECT Trim(a.FirstName) & ' ' & Trim(a.LastName) AS employee_name,
a.city, a.street + ' ' + a.housenum AS address
FROM Employees AS a
```

The result will be as this:

```
employee_name        city          address
john silver         london       ukitgam 780/19
gret garbo          berlin       akstrass 102
le chen             berlin       NULL
daniel defo         rome        corso vinchi 25
maggi forth         london       NULL
voich lutz          paris        NULL
anna poperplatz     milan      via domani 15/4
```

but I want this:

```
employee_name           city                  address
john silver            london               ukitgam 780/19
gret garbo             berlin               akstrass 102
le chen                berlin               oppenhaim
daniel defo            rome                corso vinchi 25
maggi forth            london              bolken str
voich lutz             paris               pinchi platz
anna poperplatz        milan             via domani 15/4
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Trim(a.FirstName) & ' ' & Trim(a.LastName) AS employee_name,
a.city, a.street & (' ' +a.housenum) AS address
FROM Employees AS a
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use [**ISNULL()**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function for `housenum` column.

```
SELECT Trim(a.FirstName) & ' ' & Trim(a.LastName) AS employee_name,
a.city, a.street + ' ' + ISNULL(a.housenum,'') AS address
FROM Employees AS a
```

You are getting address as NULL when `housenum` column value is **NULL** because **NULL** concatenated with anything gives **NULL** as final result.

As has been posted in other answers , you can also use **[COALESCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)** to handle NULL values.

**COALESCE** is in the SQL '92 standard and supported by more different databases. On other hand **ISNULL()** is provided in SQL Server only as so would not be much portable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COALESCE` to handle the `null`s:

```
SELECT Trim(a.FirstName) & ' ' & Trim(a.LastName) AS employee_name,
       Coa.city, a.street + Coalesce(' ' + a.housenum,'')  AS address
FROM Employees AS a
```

Note that I apply the `coalesce` to `' ' + a.housenum` so in case `housenum` is `null` you won't get a trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCAT(col1,col2)` function instead of using + as follows:

```
SELECT Trim(a.FirstName) & ' ' & Trim(a.LastName) AS employee_name,
a.city, CONCAT(a.street,a.housenum) AS address
FROM Employees AS a
```

Comment: You can ask me here only if you have any more queries.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
  SELECT concat_ws(a.FirstName,a.LastName) AS employee_name,
 concat_ws(a.city, a.street,a.housenum) AS address
 FROM Employees AS a
```

as it ignores null . You will get the result you expected

Answer (score 0):

just replace

housenum

with

ISNULL ( housenum , '' )

The result would be the housenum or an empty string